# Advisable to pass nested variables from this.state into child component?

Tags: reactjs

At the parent component I have the following

```
this.state = {
  title: props.title || "Notifications for Vendor",
  logged_in: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false,
  name: props.name || '',
  email_contacts: props.email_contacts || [],
  topics: props.topics || {}
};
```

in the constructor.

I called the child component like this

```
 <TopicSubscriptionAutocomplete
      id="quotation.status.sent_to_vendor"
      placeholder="(None selected)"
      inputProps={{
        name: "topics['quotation.status.sent_to_vendor']",
        onChange: this.handleChange,
        value: this.state.topics["quotation.status.sent_to_vendor"]
      }}
      vendor={this.props.match.params.vendor_id}
      className={classes.dropdown + ' ' + classes.firstDropdown}
    />
```

Then inside the child component

```
handleChange(selectedValue) {
  this.props.inputProps.onChange({target: {name: this.props.inputProps.name, value: selectedValue}});
  this.setState({value: selectedValue})
}
```

Will it still work?

If not how else? The reason is that the topics may be dynamic.

Comment: are you facing any issue doing so?

Answer (score 0):

If `quotation.status.sent_to_vendor` this won't work because the whole string is considered as a key instead of treating quotation, status and sent_to_vendor as keys